# PlotMarker -> Automatic with Show

Tags: plotting, marker

I am trying to use `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` or its equivalent for `Show[ListPlot[..., PlotMarkers -> Automatic], ListPlot[...] ,...]` to make each list plot display a different plot marker shape/type, but it gives the same shape for every list plot. Is there some way to do this, or do I have to give each list plot `PlotMarkers -> "shape"` manually?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since every `ListPlot` is generated separately and combined later, each one will have the first from a set of default markers. You can put multiple data sets into one `ListPlot`, will that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Wrong

```
Show[ListPlot[Range[5]], ListPlot[1 + Range[5]],
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

No better

```
Show[
   ListPlot[Range[5], PlotMarkers -> Automatic],
   ListPlot[1 + Range[5], PlotMarkers -> Automatic],
   PlotRange -> All]
```

Both of the above give

[image: show]

Correct

```
ListPlot[{Range[5], 1 + Range[5]}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]